# HashSlots in Redis Cluster

Tags: java, redis, lua, jedis, redis-cluster

Currently I am having the below lua script
local job_id = KEYS[1]; local job_body = KEYS[2];
if job_id ==nil or job_id == '' then error('Invalid job id') end; if job_body ==nil or job_body == '' then error('Invalid job body') end;
redis.call('HSET','JOB:WORK_BODY',job_id,job_body);

which is called using jedis cluster implementation using evalsha
something like: connection.evalsha(script, 2, jobId, jobBody)

This was working fine in normal redis but fails in cluster saying "JedisClusterOperationException: Keys must belong to same hashslot"

Documentation speaks about adding {} to the keys. But couldnt get where to and how to add in the above code.

Any help on this would be really helpful. Got stuck in this for a long time now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `job_id` and `job_body` as `ARGV`, instead of `KEYS`.

```
# script.lua
local job_id = ARGV[1]; local job_body = ARGV[2]

# other code
```

I'm not familiar with Jedis, but you can try the following code:

```
connection.evalsha(script, 1, "JOB:WORK_BODY", jobId, jobBody)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.
But no luck, still facing the same issue

Comment: My bad. You need to set a key, since you connect to a cluster. See the updated answer.